# Shiny app. Get headers from uploading table

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I would like to get headers from table and then use them in checkboxGroupInput for further sorting.The headers not equal, because tables are different.

I'm uploading tables using this code:

**Server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
server <- function(input, output) {

  names <- reactive({ read_excel(input$file1$name, sheet = 1,
                      range = "A1:P1", col_names = TRUE)
                    })
}
```

**Ui.R**

```
 library(shiny)
 library(shinythemes)
 ui <- fluidPage(

  theme=shinytheme("readable"),

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("App_1"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(


      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Choose File",
                multiple = FALSE),

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),


      checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Columns in diamonds to show:", names(names) )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, I would first set the choices to `NA` for  `checkboxGroupInput` in your UI. Next I would add the following code to your server:

```
observe({
 if (is.null(input$file1))
  return(NULL)
 cnames <- colnames(names())
 updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "show_vars", choices = cnames)
})
```

This code will update the choices for the checkboxGroup with the names of the columns from your file.

A few side notes as well. First, I got an error that you were missing the `mainPanel` argument in your `sidebarPanel`. Second, note that you want to use `colnames` instead of `names` here. Lastly, I would recommend using `input$file1$datapath` instead of `input$file1$name` in `read_excel`.

Hope this helps.